# Python: Find the nearest neighbor pairs in a list of point coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a list of coordinates. The first element of tuple is the slice number. The 2nd and 3rd are the xy coordinate. Now I want to find the set of points which are nearest. So If I have 6 slices, there must be a return list with pairs of 6 coordinates which belong to each other.

Example dataset:

```
array=[(0.0, 333.56146977926664, 3008.7982175915004),
(0.0, 172.37833716058688, 1649.3905288621663),
(0.0, 77.50966744006188, 2283.89997422016),
(0.0, 116.57814612355257, 581.9223534943867),
(0.0, 340.0307776756536, 2184.111532373366),
(0.0, 313.93527847976634, 318.1736354983754),
(0.0, 547.9143957324791, 1097.8102318962867),
(0.0, 432.92846166979683, 215.97046269421205),
(0.0, 449.53987956249233, 336.3028143050264),
(0.0, 503.6196838777661, 167.45041095890411),
(0.0, 503.75169204737733, 343.3688663282572),
(0.0, 636.3648922234131, 2193.3168988924617),
(0.0, 717.4529664732162, 3457.784309632166),
(0.0, 846.2564443852878, 603.3166955055681),
(0.0, 1535.2396900242939, 3131.323672911694),
(0.0, 1469.1578125128474, 1707.8372376026773),
(0.0, 1396.379645056139, 92.53690691778341),
(0.0, 1415.425816023739, 2627.336980712166),
(0.0, 1486.3829039812647, 2626.749414519906),
(0.0, 1646.0350180728474, 507.73284624177455),
(0.0, 1604.0196393706212, 901.6203629263811),
(0.0, 1842.0375522573343, 1814.7994048597038),
(0.0, 2007.165137614679, 979.321865443425),
(0.0, 2147.671282186245, 1843.2944622254672),
(0.0, 2070.921192867391, 3782.243082598893),
(0.0, 2065.1681055155877, 478.74772182254196),
(0.0, 2104.848780487805, 533.6113821138212),
(0.0, 2380.856736123359, 1090.9250925949254),
(0.0, 2279.9033647854726, 745.2587146163432),
(0.0, 2292.8939526730937, 831.2670902716915),
(0.0, 2474.9004065643826, 3268.4603377155236),
(0.0, 2453.183810923341, 3408.1759735488613),
(0.0, 2585.0363084532373, 2374.9155425659474),
(0.0, 2773.128683566231, 725.2908866474347),
(0.0, 2624.9709841731856, 915.2607786065126),
(0.0, 2714.8521421572996, 971.4124877527389),
(0.0, 2798.4276574009355, 2330.6135276090113),
(0.0, 2783.3074825567405, 934.502365867351),
(0.0, 2865.471879033745, 3063.324635810437),
(0.0, 2908.2407809110628, 1320.8433839479392),
(1.0, 154.6280574750466, 606.6849292530437),
(1.0, 376.7177563593005, 2208.945026828299),
(1.0, 364.8949263599067, 344.15018742067826),
(1.0, 583.3997824789169, 1120.0000411711828),
(1.0, 468.60350318471336, 243.40191082802548),
(1.0, 538.9199157860642, 190.7942831693591),
(1.0, 540.7046009389671, 364.90441314553993),
(1.0, 679.3226418205804, 3433.8067694591027),
(1.0, 673.7542547115934, 2217.11924614506),
(1.0, 889.9705312329176, 620.7821398399841),
(1.0, 1499.330283784636, 3113.874643753002),
(1.0, 1121.688416543088, 3732.0913165266106),
(1.0, 1501.9564873611191, 1734.5836790922503),
(1.0, 1433.621833357739, 118.40620881534632),
(1.0, 1682.7643898580789, 528.6640451282664),
(1.0, 1642.755639624492, 926.4499789827659),
(1.0, 1882.9388528959287, 1840.9367077636455),
(1.0, 2185.5049122512387, 1865.852288185406),
(1.0, 2101.435029585799, 498.7003550295858),
(1.0, 2139.9415746348413, 557.1467759173495),
(1.0, 2413.369506990553, 1121.0576549175898),
(1.0, 2317.6752836026126, 763.9984530766586),
(1.0, 2329.424714229405, 851.9824595979503),
(1.0, 2438.439804695262, 3244.4834643881113),
(1.0, 2420.7388542963886, 3385.5640099626403),
(1.0, 2623.1869865740236, 2399.7963666630476),
(1.0, 2675.525004799386, 812.9451430216932),
(1.0, 2657.7694468189034, 948.9477347661497),
(1.0, 2737.3965619442797, 977.0773562537048),
(1.0, 2758.0705197325856, 1038.3683416001725),
(1.0, 2759.6937973617737, 669.6233511086164),
(1.0, 2836.7935110202584, 2354.228267421443),
(1.0, 2812.892162448116, 961.1602506714414),
(1.0, 428.61883088048717, 1787.5984283811215),
(1.0, 125.98787227509979, 2312.208090267117),
(2.0, 337.10235964928484, 3008.4183779818836),
(2.0, 172.18748968333261, 1650.019251987316),
(2.0, 79.05630596448627, 2285.681286993474),
(2.0, 120.59550561797752, 583.0968845760981),
(2.0, 341.2470033058268, 2182.697769197769),
(2.0, 311.12108963690093, 318.82918379131144),
(2.0, 545.8929083744167, 1095.6975712707547),
(2.0, 429.5308275144852, 221.87297578368742),
(2.0, 448.40031011758623, 337.2594650471637),
(2.0, 500.984451750145, 164.64977760587894),
(2.0, 636.0321566075593, 2195.677728973483),
(2.0, 716.7293186080433, 3460.95140654303),
(2.0, 845.8828675783573, 602.3421387921516),
(2.0, 1535.26017827827, 3127.550027046247),
(2.0, 1158.3666919050597, 3758.0845047239686),
(2.0, 1464.3599847675866, 1709.9265908748323),
(2.0, 1395.8473628318584, 96.62223008849557),
(2.0, 1417.4062823610632, 2615.9252675181224),
(2.0, 1487.533211456429, 2615.8653260207193),
(2.0, 1645.2234663632826, 502.6575851022424),
(2.0, 1609.6065007403229, 898.9125008813368),
(2.0, 1855.3184030907921, 1815.9022279459111),
(2.0, 1870.8715660298424, 1979.6834472179612),
(2.0, 2004.820143884892, 975.848201438849),
(2.0, 2152.2386336712934, 1845.8399522879715),
(2.0, 2064.784335981839, 474.4242905788876),
(2.0, 2101.247747747748, 532.5915915915916),
(2.0, 2378.1860178079924, 1098.1421760767212),
(2.0, 2279.763305997749, 736.8652194886638),
(2.0, 2292.220562217417, 828.8089247100452),
(2.0, 2475.482818773363, 3265.9790945590476),
(2.0, 2460.545879086205, 3408.4455383061972),
(2.0, 2587.7001645639057, 2374.7207167672336),
(2.0, 2777.0123269458654, 733.5197693574959),
(2.0, 2623.891525049658, 918.2103288457295),
(2.0, 2707.5055488701696, 948.1838481080358),
(2.0, 2728.9928986442865, 1012.8095545513235),
(2.0, 2801.1314431698643, 2329.664604518359),
(2.0, 2777.031130820399, 920.7952993348115),
(2.0, 2866.286997193639, 3064.177923292797),
(2.0, 2909.7604712041884, 1317.9070680628272),
(3.0, 157.26388004449086, 1633.8971530944073),
(3.0, 63.67491895078102, 2270.573312702623),
(3.0, 106.90561963190184, 566.6600245398773),
(3.0, 367.2937136901629, 3023.2236402191747),
(3.0, 324.9559239582667, 2168.772604493375),
(3.0, 309.9233307424951, 305.357814310226),
(3.0, 529.6920537916766, 1079.0594923211586),
(3.0, 414.9144941240038, 209.41901931649332),
(3.0, 486.1743528597254, 147.9357282972422),
(3.0, 620.9823211314476, 2181.4336522462563),
(3.0, 747.0673195115955, 3476.260099975416),
(3.0, 830.2220659995038, 587.1107435282441),
(3.0, 1564.271350026497, 3143.328428533576),
(3.0, 1447.2135826080168, 1694.8505366691386),
(3.0, 1379.2560933268524, 82.5819734740643),
(3.0, 1414.0898379970545, 2637.6224840451646),
(3.0, 1458.7942639742464, 2632.1287679250804),
(3.0, 1517.2141613464887, 2632.6935577481136),
(3.0, 1628.7177629761502, 486.4310598852021),
(3.0, 1592.5086746302616, 884.4677901023891),
(3.0, 1846.0530963067265, 1798.3329519786441),
(3.0, 1854.721832632071, 1959.0901622921258),
(3.0, 2140.705506419401, 1827.9028408396168),
(3.0, 2046.6188630490956, 459.6313522825151),
(3.0, 2100.54031783402, 3798.304787129684),
(3.0, 2089.9236276849642, 518.0429594272076),
(3.0, 2362.4917481532502, 1082.4142175546672),
(3.0, 2263.1660548213413, 717.3157427802252),
(3.0, 2275.2605606758834, 812.102534562212),
(3.0, 2502.8201961695036, 3282.5997377120843),
(3.0, 2492.2876712328766, 3424.5829975825945),
(3.0, 2572.046443965517, 2362.7854166666666),
(3.0, 2618.7545978589073, 753.6802834826442),
(3.0, 2600.3548616882345, 902.7820254066247),
(3.0, 2689.188485206103, 918.132850037933),
(3.0, 2822.238917763738, 692.1082028778023),
(3.0, 2713.429400386847, 994.9756838905776),
(3.0, 2785.0664297628546, 2313.4155002779994),
(3.0, 2769.067081895463, 901.3574614931404),
(3.0, 2895.185851318945, 3078.8379450285925),
(3.0, 2894.081445993031, 1303.1498257839721),
(4.0, 323.2980014095852, 2995.5082158679015),
(4.0, 189.00062107109585, 1661.3407749960134),
(4.0, 94.69584245076587, 2304.1963718500742),
(4.0, 138.99071904003, 594.3969250960907),
(4.0, 356.0687429605538, 2199.471494197598),
(4.0, 339.94278226043934, 335.9263649213735),
(4.0, 561.0918771562345, 1107.1995040660424),
(4.0, 444.95715341049004, 240.15735040630386),
(4.0, 515.9579145492189, 174.8035761340109),
(4.0, 521.9724964739069, 361.19340620592385),
(4.0, 652.1437428698973, 2213.3314815733347),
(4.0, 703.7371733205066, 3448.0016033349366),
(4.0, 863.0894711992446, 615.1586402266289),
(4.0, 1519.4442919707187, 3125.3200876862925),
(4.0, 1477.601623813873, 1724.884220058513),
(4.0, 1413.3926438653637, 112.9267779587405),
(4.0, 1473.6105100463678, 2606.236991241628),
(4.0, 1656.7474928951754, 515.9234802208213),
(4.0, 1621.8129663859793, 915.8049565276922),
(4.0, 1876.2702648647105, 1826.619646275608),
(4.0, 1891.8117573483428, 1991.976235146967),
(4.0, 2173.9414860981046, 1854.8787176671942),
(4.0, 2056.983448913546, 3768.833934350439),
(4.0, 2075.197315150224, 487.019603665033),
(4.0, 2117.8430769230768, 548.3425641025641),
(4.0, 2393.594353853348, 1111.8233033653628),
(4.0, 2292.022869692533, 742.7756954612006),
(4.0, 2304.9634436117713, 839.7576311460427),
(4.0, 2459.5847136835887, 3257.187065424575),
(4.0, 2448.2789465232054, 3396.4231572185645),
(4.0, 2601.3766628260187, 2390.8952201389616),
(4.0, 2652.0092467353616, 780.6522145439343),
(4.0, 2645.946173800259, 919.6041319251436),
(4.0, 2736.3547049441786, 956.7454545454545),
(4.0, 2824.591325417979, 814.5812454567482),
(4.0, 2752.9186953438902, 1025.5029543843063),
(4.0, 2815.841896499733, 2343.718099788917),
(4.0, 2799.1525048681183, 923.3706850770047),
(4.0, 2876.0865684798177, 644.4555588202887),
(4.0, 2849.6915052160953, 3051.0775894187777),
(4.0, 2926.4961904761903, 1333.1619047619047),
(5.0, 342.7083988173585, 3010.581102783726),
(5.0, 172.66986024652678, 1644.3937337675723),
(5.0, 79.33176646910553, 2287.3308808501943),
(5.0, 123.69916165562041, 579.1842163016285),
(5.0, 341.2068281113469, 2186.740931219573),
(5.0, 324.24324719150366, 322.68505397864226),
(5.0, 545.4950787372192, 1091.116850511232),
(5.0, 429.0323831242873, 226.10558722919043),
(5.0, 499.3247200058561, 158.63070053436792),
(5.0, 506.5545222465354, 352.4772064186725),
(5.0, 637.0303665431858, 2199.3088808734647),
(5.0, 719.7670217505772, 3464.994248450727),
(5.0, 845.3587260761026, 601.5611619638399),
(5.0, 1536.9222192362013, 3135.167320414663),
(5.0, 1462.9025670193, 1712.0848974329806),
(5.0, 1397.2887252583935, 96.53935013173006),
(5.0, 1389.9905660377358, 2628.7861635220124),
(5.0, 1433.833930046819, 2622.1148443954835),
(5.0, 1491.3909811694748, 2623.4930624380577),
(5.0, 1640.366485013624, 500.02659137914054),
(5.0, 1603.046150785757, 902.7337709700948),
(5.0, 1874.4067119887775, 1811.3451494550557),
(5.0, 2163.080461618503, 1840.8093648015893),
(5.0, 2074.5243486073673, 3782.4163522012577),
(5.0, 2056.7912423625253, 470.181466395112),
(5.0, 2105.2317497103127, 524.8532251834686),
(5.0, 2375.7653644855686, 1097.8645923046913),
(5.0, 2274.869907197827, 725.5888411045722),
(5.0, 2286.78021978022, 823.1176669484362),
(5.0, 2477.5736712443654, 3273.0428766118043),
(5.0, 2461.705685618729, 3413.5393416651996),
(5.0, 2585.4316079444975, 2374.4842538430144),
(5.0, 2722.678243517861, 781.2931102024827),
(5.0, 2630.109522052039, 902.0422587193209),
(5.0, 2721.1595322390303, 938.8852054500591),
(5.0, 2739.7317179655097, 1009.6524776249727),
(5.0, 2799.6063686385432, 2328.704373190728),
(5.0, 2783.330575692964, 904.1339019189766),
(5.0, 2858.7568411552347, 622.506119133574),
(5.0, 2866.938534507792, 3064.189139483109),
(5.0, 2910.775520077407, 1317.6782776971456)]
```

**So a return could be: [(coordinate0,coordinate1,coordinate2,coordinate3,coordinate4,coordinate5),(coordinate0,coordinate1....]**

**Minimal Example, where coordinates do not change through the slices:**

```
list=[(0,1,1),
(0,2,2),
(1,1,1),
(1,2,2),
(2,1,1),
(2,2,2),
(3,1,1),
(3,2,2),
(4,1,1),
(4,2,2)]
```

**return**

```
coordinates=[[(0,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,1,1),[(0,2,2),(1,2,2),(2,2,2),(3,2,2),(4,2,2)]
```

There is also the possibility that in the slices are not the same number of coordinates

Comment: So for each `arr[i,:,:]`, you want the six points which are closest together in an euclidean sense?

Comment: The points are belong together though the time variable (sliceNumber). I alsway know the number of slices. But in some slices points are missing, in other slices new points appear. So there is the possibility that some points could not be assigned.

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of input and output? for example four slice numbers and two points per slice number?

Comment: This sounds like an optimal assignment problem but I'm not sure I follow. You might read the famous crocker and grier paper on tracking objects through microscope images (1996?). As I read what you wrote I think it's more complex than you think.

Comment: @Liwellyen  did you try the  naive approach:  for a given point on a slice, compute the distance to all the points in the next slice, take the nearest point, repeat for all slice, repeat for all point in the first slice... ?

Comment: No i didnt. is there a fast numpy/scipy way to do that?

Comment: There is surely fine tuned way to do this, but as long as your data is not huge, the simplest the better... there is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html  which provide "quick nearest-neighbor lookup"

Comment: How will the coordinates change? Are you looking to associate points in any slice with a point in the first slice, or are you looking to associate points in any slice with a point in the previous slice?

Comment: The second variant. The most efficient way would be to look at all coordinates, but  because the coordinates could move along the slices, I think you have to look from slice to slice

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code, looking for the nearest point from one slice to the next:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def get_points_on_slice(i):
    return slices[ slices[:, 0] == i ][:, (1, 2)]

# Look for the nearest point slice by slice:
n_last_slice = int( np.max(slices[:, 0]) )
start_points = get_points_on_slice(0)
path_through = np.arange(start_points.shape[0]).reshape(1, -1)

for i in range(1, n_last_slice+1):

    get_nearest = KDTree(get_points_on_slice(i))

    previous_points = get_points_on_slice(i-1)[path_through[-1, :]]
    distance, idx_nearest = get_nearest.query(previous_points)

    path_through = np.vstack((path_through, idx_nearest))

# `path_through` is a (nbre slices x nbr points on the first slice) array
# with the index of the nearest point on the corresponding slice

# Graph
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
for path_idx in path_through.T:
    path_coords = [get_points_on_slice(i)[idx] for i, idx in enumerate(path_idx)]

    plt.plot(*zip(*path_coords), 'x-', alpha=.8);

plt.axis('equal');
```

The result is:

[image: graph of the merged points]

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly trying a sort of tracking, as your data shows:
[image]

But some particles cross each other, so it will be difficult to track them in this case.
The following shows the groups that can be isolated for a fixed radius.

[KDTree.query_ball_point](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point) is the perfect tool for that :

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
from collections import Counter
arr=np.array(array)
points=arr[:,1:]
tree=KDTree(points)
csize=90   # radius of groups
res=tree.query_ball_point(points,csize)
res2=[tuple(l) for l in res] #hashable
groups = [k for k,v in Counter(res2).items() if len(k)==v] 
#isolated neighborhoods : all neighbors have same neighborhood.

centers=[np.take(points,group,0).mean(0) for group in groups] # centers of groups

for (x,y) in centers:
    scatter(x,y,300,edgecolor="black",c="white")  # plot the groups

for i in range(6): #plot the points
    _,x,y=(arr[arr.T[0]==i]).T
    plot(x,y,'o',label=str(i))
legend()
show()
```